# Orbits and indices of vector fields

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, dg.differential-geometry

I'm afraid this might be an exercise in differential topology (in which case a reference to a book where it is would be very much appreciated); apologies in advance. Given an analytic vector field (in $\mathbb{R}^m$) with an isolated zero (say at $0$) of index $k$, is there always a small neighbourhood of $0$ such that the orbits of the vector field always yield the same (up to diffeomorphism) model foliation?

This is probably only of interest when $m=2$. If further $k=1$, the answer is quite easily found to be "no": there are straight radial lines, (in complex coordiantes $z \mapsto \alpha z$, $\alpha$ being anything but pure imaginary) and concentric circles ($z \mapsto \pm i z$). When $k \neq 1$, I've seen a few books saying it should look like this or this (and I thought I convinced myself of it some time ago) but I fail to retrieve a clear argument...

Presumably, when $m \geq 3$, something tells me there is too much freedom to have another answer than "no" (for all $k$), but are there any? How much may one expect this to change for smooth instead of analytic vector fields?

Comment: You might want to look up the Poincaré-Dulac theorem.